# Rearrange Points that are too near to each other

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, design-patterns, math

My case is that I am dynamically positioning a bunch of icons on a static map image, each by CSS, positioned absolutely. Now it often happens, that two or even more points are too near to each other, so the icons overlap and they are not anymore distinguishable.

I am looking for an algorithm to find these "too near to each other" points, and then spread their icons out in a manner that they do not overlap each other anymore.

I am thinking of a radial spread, like finding the average middle point of all points that are too near and then spread them out relatively to that point.

Is there any pattern for such a problem of which you may know?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Change icon colour based on stacking depth/proximity.

Comment: Am I reading correctly that you are labeling points on a 2-dimensional map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few solutions that might solve your problem:

- Use a solution to the [closest pair of points problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) to find the two icons that are closest to one another.  If the closest pair is "too close" by your definition, you can move them apart from one another and repeat this process.
- Use a spatial data structure like a k-d tree or R-tree to store all the points.  You can then execute fast nearest-neighbor searches to find points that are close to one another and move them apart.
- Use a [force-directed layout algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) to find a layout for the points that globally minimizes some energy function.  Algorithms like Fruchterman-Reingold are pretty straightforward to code up and produce good results.

Hope this helps!